# What is the proj4 for World Behrmann (54017)?

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, proj

I have this in an old SDE database:

`PROJCS["World_Behrmann",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Behrmann"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

The spatialreference.org postgresql spatial_ref_sys insert statement doesn't have a proj4 value.

Comment: It's an ellipsoidal (Lambert) cylindrical equal area with standard parallels at +/-30.

Comment: This handles perhaps your case https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oracle_ugent/2WUt9HmcrHU.  Proj4 string would be then `'+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'`

Comment: @user30184: that's what I'm using now. Feel free to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behrman is special case of cylindrical equal area. There is some information about this as well as a warning about an issue in some old Proj4 versions in this thread http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oracle_ugent/2WUt9HmcrHU.

Proj4 string to use is

> +proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84
>   +units=m +no_defs