# Gall-Peters or other cylindric equal-area projections in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Is it possible to use Gall-Peters or other cylindric equal-area projections like Hobo–Dyer in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gall-Peters can be used in QGIS with a custom CRS. See my example at [Getting Borders as SVG using Peters Projection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194295/getting-borders-as-svg-using-peters-projection)

For Hobo-Dyer, see the projection string given in [Proj4 string for Hobo–Dyer projection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170086/proj4-string-for-hobo-dyer-projection)

Behrmann is also possible, see [What is the proj4 for World Behrmann (54017)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138287/what-is-the-proj4-for-world-behrmann-54017)